# How to login to server with Python Script

Tags: python

My Bash script is below

```
SSHPASS='xxxx@12345' sshpass -e ssh xx@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

How to login server with python, I don't need to execute any command after login. Just want to login. I have tried `paramiko` module but could not help

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('xx.xx.xx.xx', username="xx", password="xx@xx")
```

Comment: Wht is the use-case? SSH is meant for interactive login; especially for executing commands.

Comment: I just want to login , no need to execute commands

Answer (score 0):

With paramiko imported:

```
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
    client.connect(host, username="user123", password="password123")
```

Although, have in mind that this doesn't keep you in a session after the script have executed, it is only to execute further actions while connected to specified server.

So if you want a quick way to open a terminal connected to a server this is not the way to go.

Comment: What exactly is the goal with this? For what purpose are you logging in to the server?

Comment: i just want to log in to server, like `ssh name@ip` with password, i need to do it in python script

Comment: why in a python script though? what will you do once loggen on? If we knew more about this it would be easier to identify a good way to go about it.